# DynamoDB Table Vs Relational Table with Primary Key

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, relational-database

I understand Key value databases like DynamoDB are used for faster access and we can retrieve the data based on a specific key. Provided I don't want infinite scalability can I not use a relational table with Primary key (access Key) and other Nullable attributes for doing the same.

What are the counter arguments for the same.

Relational db like Postgre also now support Json attributes and have inbuilt functions to parse them.

What unique advantage does a key value db gives me when I dont require to have PetaBytes of data.

Comment: You're asking for an opinion, yet giving very few specifics. I'd say none of the claims in your q are true in general: Key-value stores don't necessarily give faster access for single-key structures; they aren't necessarily more appropriate for a petabyte sized datastore; nullable attributes have nothing to do with it, and should be avoided in any schema.  Suggest you first go do some research and cite some authoritative texts for your claims.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Whether its key-value or an SQL database is a question of syntactical convenience. You can actually query DynamoDB with SQL-like queries with [PartiQL](https://partiql.org/).

But there is more to the story. As you mentioned you could just use a SQL with nullable attributes.  To store a null value would consume a small amount of storage.  SQL Server has "Spares Columns" that results in nulls not taking up space, but they use extra storage overhead.

The main benefits of DynamoDB are less about the syntax. It's with easily providing a way to get scalable, constant time access to data using the partition key (or a secondary partition key) that isn't highly dependent on table size or number of running queries.  It's also the serverless multimaster global tables which is great for disaster recovery or global apps that can use eventual consistency, DynamoDB streams, etc.

Yes, these features could also be provided with SQL (see "newSQL" databases like CockroachDB), but perhaps SQL isn't often used for these types of databases to prevent the perception that it's ok to do ad-hoc scan queries and joins, which perform poorly with distributed partitioned databases like DynamoDB.

I cover more pros in cons in my blog post on DynamoDB: http://www.101coder.com/dynamoDBdesign

Answer (score -1):

To summarize your question:

> What advantages do NoSQL Databases like DynamoDB give me that I cannot get with an RDBMS?

This is fairly simple question with a rather complex answer.  In short, predictability at scale.

DynamoDB gives you *predictable* performance at scale. Note that I am *not* saying relational databases are slow and cannot offer blazing fast performance.  What I am saying is that the scaling strategies are different, and represent a much lager effort to maintain **predictable** performance at scale.

As a managed NoSQL database, DynamoDB and it's NoSQL peers offer a completely different way of storing, retrieving and thinking about your data.  If it were as simple as storing all data in JSON, the problem DynamoDB solves would have been solved long ago!

There's loads of information online about DynamoDB and how it compares to other DB offerings.  I'd suggest starting with the AWS re:Invent talks about DynamoDB to dig into some of the answers to you questions.

A few places to start: [DynamoDB Under The Hood](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yvBR71D0nAQ&ab_channel=AmazonWebServices), [Intro to DynamoDB Data Modeling](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DIQVJqiSUkE&ab_channel=AWSEvents), [Advanced Design Patterns with DynamoDB](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MF9a1UNOAQo&ab_channel=AWSEvents)

Comment: No thanks we don't want marketing puff here. In any case, the question is not "simple"; it's vague and not capable of a quality answer.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution AntC